# Overleaf IOP template, \printbibliography issues

Tags: latex, overleaf

So I'm using this overleaf code to write a journal style report, using the IOP template:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}

%import bib
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Firstyearreport.bib}
\addbibresource{book.bib}

%import graphics and others
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\ioptwocol
```

Mostly just text between these sections and `\cite{}` citations

```
%add sub paragraph
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\paragraph{Transmission}

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{40}
\bibliography{}
%\printbibliography
```

I'm having problems with using printbib to print out the references. Strangely it was working without those last 3 lines of code, but once I added the %sub paragraph section the printbib stopped working and without the those last three lines over leaf wont compile the latex as well. I cant really figure out what's going wrong, but a method to automate my adding my reference list on the end would be quite useful. I'd appreciate any help thats on offer.

For reproducibility:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}

%import bib
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Firstyearreport.bib}
\addbibresource{book.bib}

%import graphics and others
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\ioptwocol

%add sub paragraph
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\paragraph{Transmission}

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{40}
\bibliography{}
%\printbibliography
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] in one codeblock which we can copy and paste and directly reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please also add a link where we can download the class.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{40}
\bibliography{}` is bibtex syntax, not biblatex syntax.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by class, I've been using overleaf for this, with the template here: https://www.overleaf.com/project/60d398135d85cb73aebc57b3

Comment: Going to have to bear with me, I've only been using latex for ~ 5 hours

Comment: with class I mean the `iopart.cls` file. Your link gives `Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page.`

Comment: I tried with a random version of the class found on the internet, but then `\ioptwocol` is not defined. We really need to be able to get the file your are using.

Comment: You should be able to replicate the issue here:https://www.overleaf.com/6577419557bffjbyknmjnx                             Feel free to look at name.tex

Comment: @sleppy I just made two changes to `name.tex`: removed the incorrect `\\ \\ ` and commented `%\bibliographystyle{40}` and `%\bibliography{}`. Then `\printbibliography` should work fine.

Comment: Tiny remark: instead `\it Keywords` better write `\itshape Keywords` or `\emph{Keywords}`.

Comment: Its wierd that works since thats how I had it when it first stopped working. Thanks for that. The only issue is now th refrences are in harvard style not Vancouver

Comment: The print bib command also doesn't actually print anything either.

Comment: I just made and edit to replace the numerical style you were using with `style=vancouver`

Comment: That's what I see in the overleaf link https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwyio.png `\printbibliography` seems to work just fine

Comment: "Its wierd that works since thats how I had it when it first stopped working" The problem was that there were other errors (`\\ \\ `) in your document. This prevent latex from compiling your document, but biblatex needs a successfully compilation first before it can do its things with the references.

Comment: Have a look at report.tex, iydm, in there it doesn't

Comment: There are some `%` in abstracts in your bib file. They have special meaning in latex and you must escape them with `\%`

Comment: And then the syntax of the subfigure is wrong. You must give it a width: `\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth} ... \end{subfigure}`

Comment: and the second `}` is missing at `\caption{B CBD example of pore production current observations from (10)\cite{Fried2021}}`

Comment: I've made those changes and switched the style through both numeric and Vancouver and now the citations aren't being detected, some are missing the cite keys, but the ones that do have them still aren't being detected.

Comment: Sorry, can't help further because I get an `Project not found` error now when I try to open your url

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved it. Apparently there two different bibliography systems